# Appioum: Unable to create AndroidDriver with (URL,Capabilties)

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, java-client

I'm trying to create an Appium framework and I stuck with creating of android driver. The server (Appium REST http interface listener started on `0.0.0.0:4723`) has started, but on the client side, the driver creation keeps failing. below are the details.

**Error:
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake**

```
setup:
Java_client: 6.0.0
Appium server: same result with both 1.7.2 and 1.8.1
Cucumber+Junit+Maven
```

Code:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc; 
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UIAUTOMATOR2");

URL url=new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
AppiumDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(url,dc);
```

Failure in before hook: `AppiumController.setup()`

```
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:93)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:88)
at config.DriverCreator.setAndroidDriver(DriverCreator.java:19)
```

Comment: Try changing the url from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: I tried to localhost and 0.0.0.0, I'll try 127.0.0.1 as well.

Comment: Change your references of `AppiumDriver` to `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>` i.e. `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, dc);`

Comment: You should also probably be defining an app OR a package AND an activity in your capabilities.

Comment: @BillHileman I tried that as well and with 127.0.0.1 and still get the same error.

Comment: I start the server with with "-app ~/Downloads/app.apk" and this should not be a problem if I don't pass the package name as well

Answer (score 0):

This issue was version incompatibility. Rolled the version down to 5.0.4 and server to 1.7.2; this got rid of the error.

Comment: Hi you don't have to roll back to appium java client version to 5.0.4. You can use following versions, and you will not get that error : Appium java client version 6.0.0-BETA5, Appium server version 1.8.0 and selenium version 3.9.1.